# Creating a ".o" file from a Visual Studio 2012 project

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2012, compilation, g++

I wrote a program for class in Visual Studio 2012, and I want to run it on a Linux machine. I have tried compiling on the Linux machine, but i believe some of the libraries I used are not cross platform compatible. Is there anyway I can create an .o file that will run on Linux, that won't require me to change my code?

Language: C++
Here are the libraries I used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <climits> 
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
```

What happens when I try to compile in Linux

```
Main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
Main.cpp:110:24: error: no matching function for call to             'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::string&)’
Main.cpp:110:24: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:460:7: note: std::basic_ifstream<_CharT,     _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits     = std::char_traits<char>, std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:460:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from     ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:446:7: note: std::basic_ifstream<_CharT,     _Traits>::basic_ifstream() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:446:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:420:11: note:     std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/fstream:420:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from     ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const std::basic_ifstream<char>&’
```

Comment: What happens when you compile it on linux?

Comment: That looks like an extension from C++11 (opening a file with a `string` as argument). Try using `-std=c++11` [or `-std=c++0x` if you have an older version of gcc].

Answer (score 2):

None of the header files that you list appear to be specific to Visual Studio or Windows, so assuming you have installed the correct C++ standard library on the Linux machine, it should just compile.

If you really want to cross-compile, then you will have to download the source code for `gcc`, and the C++ standard library headers and binaries onto your Windows machine. Then build the compiler for cross-compilation (which probably means installing a "windows to Unix compatible version of gcc", such as Cygnus cygwin or gcc MingW). And it's not going to be straight forward to achieve this. Trust me, you don't want to do this unless you REALLY have to.

A better solution, if you don't want to compile on the linux machine itself for some reason, is to get a virtual machine installed on your Windows machine, and install Linux on that, then use that Linux VM as your compile system.

Edit:

To clarify, based on the edit in the question: The problem appears to be usage of C++11 features, which is presumably default in Visual Studio, where the gcc/g++ will take a more reserved approach. The solution is to tell the compiler to use the C++ 11 standard with `-std=c++11` on the command line for the build. This should allow the extension of opening a file with the name in a string to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty, you would be better off building it in something that's a little more cross platform friendly, and especially seeing it's C++, there's no reason to rely on visual studio.  Try looking at something like code::blocks to build it to run on linux.

Answer (score 1):

I think even if you find the way, that will not going to work. You need to generate .o separately in Linux Machine